# How to add prefab children to a list in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner, so please forgive me if what I'm asking is very obvious.
I'm currently trying to add children of a prefab to a list of type `Transform` but unity is not letting me, shows none and also don't let me drop.

```
[SerializeField] List<Transform> waypoints;
```

[image: Screenshot Of Editor]

Furthermore, my Waypoint gameObject only contains Transform same as Path (Empty game Object).

Comment: Trying to follow what you're saying. Instead of a list, try an array. 

[SerializeField] Transform[] waypoints;

Comment: @Mastro makes no difference for the serialization.. in the background a `List` **is** stored as array

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have **locked** the Inspector to a certain instance of your component.

What I suspect happened here is

- You selected the object in the Scene's Hierachy
- You locked the Inspector
- Then you opened the prefab in prefab edit mode
- Now you can't drag in the Waypoints from the Prefab's Hierarchy view since the Inspector you locked still points to the actual instance in the scene

[image]

What you probably actually rather want to do here is

- In the Inspector click on the little black lock in the top right! You are currently in locked mode so the Inspector doesn't update if you select a different object!
- select your `Paths(0)` object in the Hierarchy view
- if not added so far click `Add Component`, search and select your script
- here you can now reference your Waypoint objects as expected

[image]

- you might end up with duplicate instances of this component on the `Paths(0)` instance in the scene Hierarchy so delete the additional one

---

As little enhancement in order to not have to reference them all manually you could also implement a little helper

```
public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<Transform> waypoints;

    private void Awake()
    {
        UpdateWaypoints();
    }

    [ContextMenu("Update Waypoint List")]
    private void UpdateWaypoints()
    {
        waypoints.Clear();

        foreach(Transform child in transform)
        {
            waypoints.Add(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you even need it in the editor simply open the context menu of the component on the `Paths(0)` object's Inspector and hit `Update Waypoint List` and it does it all for you.

Otherwise on runtime it is called in `Awake` anyway so you actually don't even have to take care of it at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inside your script, add a [SerializeField] Gameobject parent, assign the path gameobject itself to it.

Then, to add each children to this list, do the following at the Start()

```
for (int i = 0; i < parent.transform.childCount - 1; ++i)
    {
        waypoints.add(parent.transform.GetChild(i));
    }
```